# Testing if a correlation between two variables depends on a continuous third variable

Tags: correlation, latent-variable, lavaan

Consider a data frame with three variables: $x_1$, $x_2$, and $z_1$. I want to know if the correlation between the $X$ variables depends on $z_1$. Now, this could easily be done with an interaction term in ordinary least squares regression. However, that requires me choosing one of the $X$ variables to be the independent—and the other the dependent—variable, such that there are two possible models:

$x_1 = \beta_0 + \beta_1x_2 + \beta_2z_1 + \beta_3x_2z_1 + \epsilon$

or

$x_2 = \beta_0 + \beta_1x_1 + \beta_2z_1 + \beta_3x_1z_1 + \epsilon$

And the two $\beta_3$ coefficients aren't equivalent.

I don't have a good reason to choose one model or the other; instead, I want to model the correlation between the two and predict this from $z$. **How can I do this?**

I have considered making the correlation a latent variable, such that this latent variable is loaded by $x_1$ and $x_2$, with the loadings fixed at one. This models the covariance between the two as the variance of a latent factor. However, the correlation between the two variables is *negative*, and variances cannot be negative.

I am using the `lavaan` R package for this (I have `dput` the data at the end of this post).

This models the covariance between the two:

```
> model1 <- "x1 ~~ x2"
> parameterestimates(sem(model1, dat))
  lhs op rhs    est    se      z pvalue ci.lower ci.upper
1  x1 ~~  x2 -0.025 0.107 -0.232  0.816   -0.234    0.185
2  x1 ~~  x1  1.353 0.135 10.025  0.000    1.088    1.617
3  x2 ~~  x2  1.697 0.169 10.025  0.000    1.365    2.028
```

Note that the covariance is -0.025.

I can model this as a latent variable:

```
> model2 <- "cov =~ 1*x1 + 1*x2"
> parameterestimates(sem(model2, dat))
  lhs op rhs    est    se      z pvalue ci.lower ci.upper
1 cov =~  x1  1.000 0.000     NA     NA    1.000    1.000
2 cov =~  x2  1.000 0.000     NA     NA    1.000    1.000
3  x1 ~~  x1  1.378 0.174  7.914  0.000    1.036    1.719
4  x2 ~~  x2  1.721 0.202  8.512  0.000    1.325    2.118
5 cov ~~ cov -0.025 0.107 -0.232  0.816   -0.234    0.185
Warning message:
In lav_object_post_check(object) :
  lavaan WARNING: some estimated lv variances are negative
```

Note that the variance of `cov` is equal to the covariance from `model1`. However, this is *negative*, which gives me the `warning`, as obviously variances cannot be negative.

Lastly, I can predict this from `z1`:

```
> model3 <- "cov =~ 1*x1 + 1*x2
+            cov ~ z1"
> parameterestimates(sem(model3, dat))
  lhs op rhs    est    se      z pvalue ci.lower ci.upper
1 cov =~  x1  1.000 0.000     NA     NA    1.000    1.000
2 cov =~  x2  1.000 0.000     NA     NA    1.000    1.000
3 cov  ~  z1  0.247 0.041  5.995  0.000    0.166    0.328
4  x1 ~~  x1  1.412 0.172  8.218  0.000    1.075    1.749
5  x2 ~~  x2  1.687 0.195  8.653  0.000    1.305    2.069
6 cov ~~ cov -0.140 0.099 -1.411  0.158   -0.335    0.055
7  z1 ~~  z1  1.843 0.000     NA     NA    1.843    1.843
Warning message:
In lav_object_post_check(object) :
  lavaan WARNING: some estimated lv variances are negative
```

So now I can see that the covariance is predicted by `z1`. Again, I have negative variances.

This feels close to being valid, but still feels like I'm missing something and doing it incorrectly. Any ideas on how I can predict the correlation between two variables from a third?

---

```
dat <- structure(list(x1 = c(6.5, 6, 6.75, 2.5, 6, 7, 5.5, 6, 6, 5.5, 
6, 5.5, 6.25, 5.5, 7, 6, 5.75, 6, 6, 4.25, 4, 6, 7, 7, 6, 6, 
6.5, 7, 6, 5, 1, 5, 6, 6, 7, 7, 6, 6, 6.75, 7, 6.5, 4.5, 5, 3, 
5.5, 3.5, 4, 6, 6.5, 6, 6, 6.5, 6, 5.25, 7, 6, 4, 5.25, 6.5, 
5.5, 6.5, 5, 3.75, 4.75, 5, 4.75, 5, 4.75, 6.25, 6, 6, 6, 7, 
6, 4.5, 5, 5.5, 4.5, 6, 7, 7, 6.5, 6.5, 6.25, 4, 5.25, 6, 4, 
6, 6, 5, 5.5, 5.5, 7, 4.5, 5.5, 5.25, 4.75, 5, 5.5, 5.75, 6.5, 
6, 6, 3.5, 6, 5, 5.5, 6, 6, 5, 6, 7, 6, 6, 6.75, 6, 6, 6, 6.25, 
7, 6.75, 6, 6, 6, 6, 5.75, 3.5, 5, 4.5, 4.75, 6, 7, 2.5, 6.5, 
5.5, 5.5, 5, 5, 7, 5.5, 6, 6, 6.25, 4.25, 7, 5, 4.25, 5.5, 4.75, 
5, 7, 6, 6, 5, 2, 4, 6, 5.5, 4.75, 2, 4.5, 6, 6.75, 2.5, 3.5, 
6.5, 6.25, 6, 5.5, 5.5, 5, 6, 4.5, 5.5, 5.5, 5, 3, 3, 6.5, 4.75, 
5, 6, 4.5, 6, 5.75, 6, 5.5, 4, 4, 6, 1.75, 6.25, 6, 4, 5, 6, 
6, 4, 1, 6), x2 = c(3, 2, 2.25, 2.5, 6, 3.75, 1.75, 2.75, 4.5, 
3, 4, 2.5, 3.75, 4.5, 1.5, 2, 2.75, 2.5, 2, 3.5, 4, 3.25, 1, 
1, 3.75, 5.25, 2, 1.5, 6, 2.5, 1, 1.5, 2, 3.25, 4, 2, 1.25, 1.75, 
3.25, 5.5, 1.5, 3.5, 3.25, 1.5, 5, 3.75, 1.5, 1.75, 1.75, 1.5, 
1.25, 1, 2, 5.5, 1.5, 1, 3.5, 1.5, 3.25, 1, 3.25, 2, 3.5, 3.25, 
4, 1.5, 2.25, 3, 1, 2, 3.75, 4.25, 4.75, 2, 4, 4, 2.5, 2, 2, 
2.5, 1, 3, 3.75, 2, 3.25, 3, 2.75, 4, 2, 2, 3.25, 3, 3.5, 2.5, 
5.25, 2, 5.25, 3.5, 1, 1.5, 2.75, 2.75, 2.75, 2, 3, 5.5, 3.75, 
3, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 6, 2, 1.25, 1.5, 1.75, 1, 1.25, 3, 2, 2.25, 
2, 1, 1, 2, 2.5, 1.5, 4.75, 4, 3.25, 1, 2.25, 5.25, 4.75, 1, 
2.5, 2, 1, 1, 1.5, 2.75, 5.5, 4.75, 1, 3.25, 3.25, 2, 2.75, 5, 
1.25, 1.25, 2.5, 4, 2, 1, 1, 2.25, 2.5, 2.5, 4, 4.25, 1, 1, 1, 
3, 2.25, 2, 2, 1, 2.5, 2, 6, 4.5, 1, 1, 1, 1.75, 2, 2.5, 1.25, 
4.75, 3.75, 1.5, 2.25, 2, 3, 1.25, 3.5, 1, 1, 1, 4, 2.5, 3.5, 
1.5, 3.75, 3, 1, 2.25), z1 = c(1, 1.28571428571429, 4.28571428571429, 
1, 5.71428571428571, 5.14285714285714, 3.28571428571429, 4.28571428571429, 
5.28571428571429, 1.85714285714286, 2.85714285714286, 3, 1.28571428571429, 
4.42857142857143, 3.14285714285714, 2.57142857142857, 2, 2, 2.42857142857143, 
4.28571428571429, 2.14285714285714, 1.85714285714286, 1.57142857142857, 
2.28571428571429, 4.57142857142857, 3, 2.85714285714286, 5, 2, 
3.85714285714286, 2, 2.42857142857143, 4, 3.85714285714286, 1.85714285714286, 
3.28571428571429, 1, 1.71428571428571, 2.57142857142857, 3.85714285714286, 
1.14285714285714, 2.14285714285714, 2.14285714285714, 1.71428571428571, 
1.14285714285714, 3.57142857142857, 1.28571428571429, 1, 1.14285714285714, 
1.42857142857143, 1.14285714285714, 1, 2.71428571428571, 5.14285714285714, 
6.14285714285714, 1, 4.28571428571429, 1, 3.85714285714286, 1.85714285714286, 
3.14285714285714, 3, 3.14285714285714, 3.14285714285714, 2.14285714285714, 
3.28571428571429, 2.57142857142857, 4.85714285714286, 1.42857142857143, 
4.57142857142857, 2.42857142857143, 1.14285714285714, 5.14285714285714, 
3.42857142857143, 3.85714285714286, 1.28571428571429, 2.85714285714286, 
2.42857142857143, 1.28571428571429, 7, 1.28571428571429, 5.57142857142857, 
4.14285714285714, 1.71428571428571, 1.71428571428571, 1.42857142857143, 
3.14285714285714, 1, 2.14285714285714, 3.28571428571429, 1.28571428571429, 
1.85714285714286, 1.14285714285714, 4.71428571428571, 3.71428571428571, 
2.85714285714286, 4, 3.14285714285714, 1, 1.14285714285714, 2.28571428571429, 
2.14285714285714, 2.42857142857143, 3.28571428571429, 3.28571428571429, 
3, 2.85714285714286, 4.14285714285714, 2.14285714285714, 2.28571428571429, 
4.57142857142857, 1.71428571428571, 5, 2.57142857142857, 3, 1.57142857142857, 
6.42857142857143, 1, 1, 1.71428571428571, 2.28571428571429, 1.85714285714286, 
3.28571428571429, 4.28571428571429, 1, 3.28571428571429, 3.42857142857143, 
2, 2, 2.57142857142857, 1.28571428571429, 3.85714285714286, 1.85714285714286, 
1, 4.71428571428571, 1.85714285714286, 1.28571428571429, 1.42857142857143, 
2.14285714285714, 1, 1, 2, 1.42857142857143, 1, 4.57142857142857, 
6, 2.71428571428571, 2.57142857142857, 1.14285714285714, 3.14285714285714, 
5, 5.71428571428571, 1.85714285714286, 3.71428571428571, 1.85714285714286, 
1.57142857142857, 1.57142857142857, 1.14285714285714, 2.57142857142857, 
1.57142857142857, 1.14285714285714, 2.71428571428571, 1.28571428571429, 
1.28571428571429, 1.57142857142857, 1, 1, 3.71428571428571, 1.14285714285714, 
4.28571428571429, 1.57142857142857, 2.14285714285714, 2.14285714285714, 
4.42857142857143, 4, 1, 1.14285714285714, 1, 1, 2, 2.85714285714286, 
3.57142857142857, 3.71428571428571, 4, 1.28571428571429, 2.57142857142857, 
1.42857142857143, 1.57142857142857, 1.14285714285714, 1.14285714285714, 
2, 1, 4, 2.14285714285714, 1.57142857142857, 1.14285714285714, 
3.85714285714286, 2.85714285714286, 2, 1, 2.14285714285714)), class = "data.frame", .Names = c("x1", 
"x2", "z1"), row.names = c(NA, -201L))
```

Comment: Building off the answer below, the issue may be one in which your model is practically unidentifiable. I know that you have fixed relevant paths, but the problem, stemming from the low correlation, is that in practice your latent covariance does not allow for much variance "sharing" between the two variables when the raw correlation is -.016. Such a low correlation can have a similar effect on the model as if you fixed the correlation to be 0.

Comment: See also https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/381072/how-to-test-whether-the-association-between-two-continuous-variables-varies-by-a?rq=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll preface my answer by saying that I suspect you may find it unsatisfactory.

So you want to test moderation of the $x_1$ and $x_2$ association by $z_1$. You are uncomfortable assigning either the role of cause or effect, so you're looking for a way to "hack" your way around such a decision with SEM, but you get this annoying Haywood case. There's a straightforward reason why you are getting the Haywood case, and there seems little to be done about it. But I think there's a bigger theoretical conundrum here that you may want to give more thought to.

**Why Are You Getting A Haywood Case?**

Calculating the correlation between $x_1$ and $x_2$ reveals the problem:

```
> cor(dat$x1, dat$x2)
[1] -0.0163713
```

These two observed variables have hardly anything in common. McDonald (1985) describes this as one of the common reasons why Haywood cases occur (albeit, in terms of low factor loadings). You're attempting to model the shared variance between two variables that hardly share any variance.

Common post-hoc strategies for troubleshooting Haywood cases (see [here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21476222) for some examples) don't seem to be much help for you: I tried different estimators, and constraining the residual variances of $x_1$ and $x_2$ to equality, and the Haywood case persists.

**The Theoretical Conundrum**

I think I get why you were inclined to try this SEM approach, but I'm not sure that--even if it were workable--it actually solves your problem. You seem to want to avoid the arbitrariness of assigning $x_1$ and $x_2$ to particular causal roles, but modelling a latent structure doesn't avoid this issue, it just "passes the buck of causality" so to speak. Instead of arbitrarily saying $x_1$ causes $x_2$, or $x_2$ causes $x_1$, you've implied that they share a source of mutual influence that causes their expression (though the data do not support this). But since this is just a hack-y way of trying to dodge your causality issue, it doesn't seem like you actually think there is a common cause of $x_1$ and $x_2$, or at least it wasn't your original way of thinking about the problem.

Is that any less arbitrary than assigning one variable as the cause and one as the outcome? I'm not so sure.

**What To Do?**

I think there's no way you can model away the causal ambiguity of your data; it's a design feature of your study, not a statistical bug. The next-best option might be to therefore present both approaches to the moderation that you initially described as form of sensitivity analysis. Or perhaps you will run a study later, in which you experimentally manipulate $x_1$ or $x_2$, so that you can pick one particular model in a less arbitrary way.

**References**

McDonald, R.P. (1985). *Factor Analysis and Related Methods*. Hillsdale NJ: Erlbaum.

Answer (score 1):

Let me try to clear my previous answer. Suppose in experimental trial one investigates the correlation between blood pressure (variable X1) and blood cholesterol level (variable X2) using some statistics as an estimator for the correlation coefficient. But it may turn out that the obtained values of the estimator are essentially different in various age [variable Z1] groups. Searching the correlation coefficients r in different age (Z1) groups one obtains data as a collection of pairs (r, z1) [for realizations Z1 = z1, of say "random variable" Z1]. The obtained set of pairs (statistically) belong to the graph of a function, say
r = f(z1). The next task (in modeling procedure) is to testify some known continuous functions f if they approximate well the data (r, z1). Such a function that would hypothetically fit to an obtained set of pairs (r, z1) one first should guess. Supposingly we chose for that purpose the function r = exp[- az1]. Then we must statistically verify such a hypothesis (estimating first the positive parameter a). It the given hypothesis is not supported by a statistical procedure we may try some other function as a model for the considered dependence r from z1. Until we find a proper function which fits to the set of the previously obtained data (r, z1). This is one of versions of the so called "third variable effect" problem. As far as I am oriented this set of problems is only considered in frameworks of pure statistic. I couldn't find any proper analytical model for the third variable effect on the ground of the pure probability theory. This rather should be a joint probability distribution of the three random variables (X1, X2, Z1). Such probability distributions I provided in my recent publication which should appear in July. I hope this time my attempt to explain my view on the considered dependence will be more successful.   Jerzy F.

Comment: I would just edit one of your answers and delete the answer. There is no reason to post multiple answers.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but what if you consider as a model the (any) correlation coefficient r  between X1 and X2 as a (continuous ?) function of realizations z1 of Z1. For example, let r(z1) = rexp[- az1], for an estimated parameter a. To verify such a "hypothesis" estimate first r for a given value z1. Then do it for other value z1 and so on...
If the data were not consistent with the model exp[ -az1] try other models such as, for example, r = r(1 - exp[- az1] ) or r = 2/pi(arctan(bz1)) or other. If, however the correlation coefficients turn out to be (statistically) constant over z1 then the independence probably will take place. If you got variance as a negative covariance then what would happen if you consider as the variance the absolute value of the covariance ??  I am not sure of above but was trying to help you.  Jerzy F.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).