# How to test whether the association between two continuous variables varies by a third variable?

Tags: r, regression, correlation, multiple-regression, association-measure

If I have two continuous variables, and want to check whether their association varies by a categorical variable (e.g. gender), is there a formal statistical test for this?

I know I can create a linear model in R and add an interaction term to the model, but I wanted to check whether there's a statistical test for association between two variables stratified by a third.

Moreover, is there something like the Pearson Correlation coefficient, but stratified by a third categorical variable?

Comment: Related:  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/56969/meaning-of-partial-correlation/56984#56984

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about formal tests, but anyhow I would start with visualization. R has a function `coplot` which is convenient for this, and can be used to condition on one or two variables. Examples can be found in multiple posts, see [Investigate correlation conditional on a threshold](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/235442/investigate-correlation-conditional-on-a-threshold/299958#299958)  and   [Can I analyze or model a conditional correlation?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/203494/can-i-analyze-or-model-a-conditional-correlation/368228#368228)   and   [What is the physical significance of cumulative correlation coefficient?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/239645/what-is-the-physical-significance-of-cumulative-correlation-coefficient/371412#371412)

As for inference, links in [Can I analyze or model a conditional correlation?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/203494/can-i-analyze-or-model-a-conditional-correlation/368228#368228) can be helpful. 
I have found very little published about conditional correlations. One reason can be the following: Look at a random vector $(X,Y,Z)$ with multivariate normal distribution.  Then, in the conditional distribution of $(X,Y)$ given $Z=z$, the correlation of $X, Y$ do not depend on $z$, it is always a constant. The proof is a simple exercise in matrix calculations.  Since much of descriptive statistics historically was informed by the normal distribution, conditional correlation was not a natural topic.

A natural question would be to look for a copula model where the conditional correlation is linear.